# I am trying to declare some types and keep getting TS1131 errors. Data come from API

Tags: angular, typescript

So I understand the issue and know that the object need to be labeled. But the data from the API comes back without any specific label. Just an Object in an array.

Now when I only write for the first object only, everything is well. But I need data from the second object aswell. So, I need to declare the types.

Here is My code.

This is the data from the API .json

Those objects are two distinct objects that need to be accessed separately.

```
{

label_1: {
        "arr_1": [{
            "key": "value",
        }],
        "arr_2": [{
            "key": "value"
            "arr_3": [{
                "key": "value"
            }],
            "arr_3": [{
                "key": "value"
                    "label_2": {
                        "key": "value"
                        "arr_4": [{
                            "key": "value"
                            "arr_5": [{
                                "key": "value"
                            }]
                        }],
                        "arr_6": [{
                            "key": "value"
                            "label_3": {
                                "key": "value"
                                "label_4": {
                                    "key": "value"
                                    }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            , **This is the Huge issue** **How can I fix this** {
                "key_x": "value_x"
                "label_x_1": {
                    "label_x_2": {
                        "key_x": "value_x"
                        "arr_x_1": [{
                            "key_x": "value_x"
                            "label_x": {
                                "key_x": "value_x"
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }] 
        }]

}


}
```

This is the Type declarations.
I can't declare **arr_3** because it has two distinct objects. I would love to access those objects separately. If I am to only declare for on object, everything works well. and TS uses the label for the array as the name of the object.

I can't do so for 2 objects in the same Array.

```
Data: {



label_1: {
        "arr_1": {
            "key": "string"
        }[];
        "arr_2": {
            "key": "string";
            "arr_2_1": {
                "key": "string"
            }[];
            
            
            **This is the issue**
            
            "arr_3": [{
                "key": "string";
                    "label_2": {
                        "key": "string";
                        "arr_4": {
                            "key": "string";
                            "arr_5": {
                                "key": "string"
                            }[];
                        }[];
                        "arr_6": {
                            "key": "string";
                            "label_3": {
                                "key": "string";
                                "label_4": {
                                    "key": "string"
                                    };
                            };
                        }[];
                    };
                };
            ,
**This is the Huge issue** **How can I fix this** 

 {
                "key_x": "string";
                "label_x_1": {
                    "label_x_2": {
                        "key_x": "string";
                        "arr_x_1": {
                            "key_x": "string";
                            "label_x": {
                                "key_x": "string"
                            };
                        }[];
                    };
                };
            };
            
          
          **end of array with issue**
            ] 
            
            
            
        }[];

};


}
```

I was expecting no issues. I tried naming the object with the name of the of the array but I get this error **Duplicate identifier 'arr_2'.ts(2300)** . Have anyone had this issue ? How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured how. Just realized that the object braces{} don't matter and everything should be put within the same {}.

Like this

```
Data: {



label_1: {
        "arr_1": {
            "key": "string"
        }[];
        "arr_2": {
            "key": "string";
            "arr_2_1": {
                "key": "string"
            }[];
            
            
            **This is the issue**
            
            "arr_3": {

                    "label_x_2": {
                        "key_x": "string";
                        "arr_x_1": {
                            "key_x": "string";
                            "label_x": {
                                "key_x": "string"
                            };
                        }[];
                    };

                "key": "string";
                    "label_2": {
                        "key": "string";
                        "arr_4": {
                            "key": "string";
                            "arr_5": {
                                "key": "string"
                            }[];
                        }[];
                        "arr_6": {
                            "key": "string";
                            "label_3": {
                                "key": "string";
                                "label_4": {
                                    "key": "string"
                                    };
                            };
                        }[];
                    };
                }[];

            
            
            
            
        }[];

};


}
```